# Anonymizing geo location coordinates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation, coordinates, geohashing

I have a csv of names, transaction amount and an exact longitude and latitude of the location where the transaction was performed. 
I want the final document to be anonymized - for that I need to change it into a CSV where the names are hashed (that should be easy enough), and the longitude and latitude are obscured within a radius of 2km.
I.e, changing the coordinates so they are within no more than 2 km from the original location, but in a randomized way, so that it is not revertible by a formula.
Does anyone know how to work with coordinates that way?

Comment: Hashing the names won't anonymize them, you will still be able to correlate all the transactions of a single person.  For the coordinates you could round them (eg to nearest 0.1 arcminute) rather than randomize them, but still deanonymization can often do things you don't expect!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [locality sensitive hashing (LSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) to map similar co-ordinates (i.e. within a 2 KM radius), to the same value with a high probability. Hence, co-ordinates that map to the same bucket would be located closer together in Euclidean space.

Else, another technique would be to use any standard hash function y = H(x), and compute y modulo N, where N is the range of co-ordinates. Assume, your co-ordinates are P = (500,700), and you would like to return a randomized value in a range of [-x,x] KM from P.

```
P = (500,700)
Range = 1000 #1000 meters for example
#Anonymize co-ordinates to within specified range
ANON_X = hash(P[0]) % Range
ANON_Y = hash(P[1]) % Range
#Randomly add/subtract range
P = (P + ANON_X*random.choice([-1,1]), P+ANON_Y*random.choice([-1,1]))
```

Comment: if you "return a randomized value in a range of [-x,x] KM from P", then all somebody needs to do is take lots of them with the same P and average them, then they find P.

Comment: also `random.choice([-1, 1])` only chooses *either* -1 or 1, nothing inbetween!

Comment: Averaging over a large number of P's would theoretically work, but I am assuming that the original co-ordinates are sparsely distributed in Euclidean space, hence you wouldn't be able to take many points to average over. `random.choice()` would work because `ANON_X` already stores a random value within the provided range, and we have to decide to either add or subtract the value in the range.